# Installing PHP 7.2 extension pdflib, module error

Tags: php, homebrew, php-extension, php-7.2, pdflib

I am trying to install pdflib on PHP 7.2 which I already had installed before. Somehow I restructured my PHP Installation with Homebrew a while ago. Before that restructure I had my extensions in `/usr/local/etc/php/7.2/extensions`. I just needed to reference my .so Files in `php.ini` and everything had been working just fine.

After the restructure I used pecl to install new extensions. Now I have my extensions in `usr/local/lib/php/pecl/20170718` which is also referenced in my `php.ini` as `extension_dir`. But if I put the `pdflib.so` inside this directory and register it in `php.ini` I get the following error:

```
Warning: PHP Startup: PDFlib: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20160303
PHP    compiled with module API=20170718
These options need to match`Warning: PHP Startup: PDFlib: Unable to 
initialize module
```

How can I solve this or is there a way to roll back to the old configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Module compiled with module API=20160303
PHP    compiled with module API=20170718
```

this message indicate, that a PDFlib DSO is loaded, which was build for an older PHP (PHP 7.1).

I see two possible problems:

- a different extension is loaded by accident. For example due to different names. (`php_pdflib.so` vs `pdf.so`)
- your PECL build go wrong, and it was build the extension against the old PHP 7.1.

I would recommend

- check your php.ini and remove all extensions with pdf
- download the latest PDFlib 9.1.2 from the website and unpack the package
- copy the correct DSO (php_pdflib.so) to your extension_dir
- add now `extension=php_pdflib.so` to your php.ini

hope that helps,
  Rainer